# Export AI from Ilustrator to SVG looks blurry and pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg

I am trying to export an AI file to SVG in order to embed it on an webpage. AI file is located [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y28k8qfsxmz2sog/AAAGbEM_56FRCtnBpZ-swPiMa?dl=0) (diente.ai).

Whatever options I choose in export menu, the svg file always looks blurry and pixelated when I open it with Chrome! I don't know how export to an svg file like example.svg that scales perfectly.

I have read many tutorials, but always recommends using Illustrator export option like I did.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  The AI file contains a gradient mesh, but this isn't supported in the SVG format, so it gets rasterized.

Comment: Hi, zachzurn. Then I will export AI file to PNG and use it in my web app. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score -1):

Yea, so I am having this issue as well, I believe that the issue resides in the image resolution that you are importing into illustrator, when the svg exports, it does not use the image resolution in illustrator, but the resolution in the image files themselves.

Comment: No the reason is clear its the gradient mesh. But apropos illustrator does not have a resolution setting.